# DAX IF statement to compare numbers in separate tables?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm having some trouble in Power BI when trying to find a specific number. I've got two tables, Table 1 and Table 2. In Table 1 I have two columns, "Consignment number" and "Subcontractor". In Table 2 I have a column "Consignment ID". Columns "Consignment number" and "Consignment ID" have a few numbers that overlap.

I need to find a way to create a calculated column in Table 1 that identifies these overlaps in the easiest way. I've been exploring using IF statements with USERELATIONSHIP statements, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions that you might have. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a relationship between "Consignment number" and "Consignment id". You can create a relationship by going to the "Modelling" tab ans selecting "Manage Relationships". Once the relationship is created you would be able to use the related function to check for overlaps:

```
Overlap Check = IF(RELATED(Table2[Consignment ID])=BLANK(),"No Overlap","Overlap")
```

*Note: This only works, if the relationship would not result in multiple mapping*

Comment: Thanks for the response! I guess my next big issue is I can't seem to set the correct relationship. Based on my understanding, it should be a one to one relationship (and all unique values that don't match return blank). However, it only allows me to set a many-to-many relationship. Any thoughts on why that might be? I really appreciate the help!

Comment: One to one relationship only works when you have only a single occurrence for each value in both the tables. In your case, the tables should be distinct at Consignment number and ID level. But ion this scenario you should be able to work with a many to one relationship. If one among the tables is at a unique key level, your calculation should work